# Plugin AngularJS depends on unknown plugin JavaScript

Tags: angularjs, intellij-idea

I'm trying to install the [AngularJS plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin?pr=webide&pluginId=6971), I go to the plugins page in the Settings and click install from disk, I choose `angular-js-plugin.jar` from my filesystem and get this error:

```
Plugin AngularJS depends on unknown plugin JavaScript
```

The JetBrains repo for JavaScript if [here](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/category/index?pr=&category_id=50) but there is no plugin called 'JavaScript'.

*Where do I get the correct pluging from?*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The JavaScript plugin is only included in the [Ultimate version](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/index.html). If you are using the community edition, it won't work.

Comment: OK... that's that *solved* then.  Thanks, I'd have been chasing that for ages if you hadn't said so.

Comment: It's worth buying an ultimate licence, in my opinion. You can accept my answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: I'm considering it.  I want to play with it a wee bit first.  You answer is accepted too.